# Logback RollingFileAppender maxHistory

Tags: java, logging, logback

I have config:

```
 <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>/logs/logFile.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>${PATTERN}</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

        <fileNamePattern>/logs/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>1MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

But,logs are not deleted after two days, in what could be the problem?
Maybe problem in:

```
<fileNamePattern>/logs/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
```

But I need save all logs

Comment: Did you check this out: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772372/logback-rollingfileappender-xml-not-rolling-over-or-deleting-old-archived-logs) ?

Comment: Ajith's answer below worked for me. Also, using totalSizeCap alongwith maxHistory makes sense, since usually its the filesystem space which is of interest for many applications

Answer (score 3):

Please set

```html
<cleanHistoryOnStart>true</cleanHistoryOnStart>
```

and check. This is false by default. This will be added under the `rollingPolicy` tag.

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html

Comment: I wish this worked for the `SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy` as well.